# Django one to one field RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I made these models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class OrderInfo(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def update_order_info(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        OrderInfo.objects.create(post=instance)
    instance.orderinfo.save()
```

In View,

```
class OrderPostWriteView(FormView):
    form_class = OrderPostForm
    template_name = 'board/order/order_post_write.html'
    success_url = '/index/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.orderinfo.position= form.cleaned_data.get('position')

            post.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            return render(self.request, 'board/order/order_post_write.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
class OrderPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    position = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'position')
```

and It returns RelatedObjectDoesNotExist Error.

Post has no orderinfo.

What shoud I do?

(I think Django System is handling .orderinfo as a post's column.. But Why?)

Comment: Please show the full traceback, the rest of that view, and whatever `form` is.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set an attribute of the related orderinfo before that object is created. Your signal is fired when the post is saved, but you explicitly don't save it because you use `commit=False`, so the signal is not fired.

In fact you don't need to do that. Just save the object normally, let the signal fire, and *then* set the position. You don't need to save the post again, but you *do* need to save the orderinfo.

(If this is the only place a Post can be created, you might be better off removing the signal altogether and just creating the orderinfo directly here, including the position, which would avoid having to save it twice.)

Comment: I solved it, thank you. It was wrong to follow examples thoughtlessly.